# What is the Everyone built-in windows security group called in Portuguese?

Tags: windows, security, language, local-groups, security-groups

I'm attempting to setup share permissions on a Brazilian server and wish to give Everyone read only access.  However, the server's language is Brazilian (Portuguese), and it looks like the security groups' names have been translated.

Does anyone know what this group is called in Portuguese?

Is there an easy way to access this group which is not language sensitive (e.g. some constant value, such as the SID (S-1-1-0) which can always be used, regardless of locale settings)?
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330.  NB: I tried using this SID, but on its own it did not work - though perhaps I need to format it in some way?

Comment: I don't have access to a Windows machine at the moment. If no one answers it, I'll provide an answer when I get home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330/pt is translated correctly, it should be "todos".

If you are writing your own program, you should use the SIDs. If you are using Windows Explorer GUI, you will need to know the localized name. If you can use a console command line, you can use the SID, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113206/cacls-windows-7-full-permissions-local-names.

Answer (score 2):

As per Werner's answer, the answer to my issue was `todos`.

Whilst waiting for replies I'd also knocked up a script to see if the OS could tell me the answer - which thankfully gives the same result as Werner mentioned.

For anyone with similar issues in future, get the SID for your group from here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330 - then use the below vbscript (amending the SID) on the machine with the foreign locale to find the translated group name.

```
Dim sid: sid = "S-1-1-0"
Dim objWMI : set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts://./root\cimv2") 
Dim objSID : set objSID = objWMI.Get("Win32_SID='" & sid & "'")

msgbox objSID.AccountName 
set objSID = nothing
set objWMI = nothing
```

For anyone not familiar with scripts, to use this you'd copy and paste the above code into notepad, save the file with the extension .vbs (e.g. c:\GetSidName.vbs) then double click on the file to run it.

Comment: You could do it directly in the command line: `wmic sysaccount where sid="S-1-1-0" get` (substitute `sysaccount` with `useraccount` or `group` where appropriate). Use `get name` instead to get only the name, which reduces the amount of output.